# !e.eoo() error in MongoDB query

Tags: json, mongodb, bson

Something is wrong with this query, and I can't tell what it is. I am sure it's something very simple:

```
db.foo.insert({
    'created at': new Date(),
    ooc: false,
    body: '<p>Moo</p>\n',
    keywords: [ 'Moo' ],
    mentioned: [],
    tags: [],
    sender: {
        _id: 'stuff',
        name: 'lambdadusk',
        'display name': 'Lambda'
    }
});
```

The error I get from Mongo is simply

```
!e.eoo()
```

I'm using MongoDB 2.0.5. Googling the error did not tell me much.

Comment: Awesome! That error is exactly the noise I make when I see code errors.

Comment: @MattGibson I hope you're not mocking my stupidity.

Comment: Not at all. That's genuine amazement that a system would make an error message that's both useless and oddly mimics the noise I'd make when seeing a useless error message. You shouldn't be feeling stupid for not knowing what to do with that one. Mongo devs have a lot to answer for if that's all your getting back.

Comment: @MattGibson Sorry then. I feel very insecure in my knowledgelessness.

Comment: Don't worry, we all know that feeling. Google tells me that eoo is end-of-object. I'd guess that the not having an end-of-object would mean that there may be a syntax error in the data. Just looking at what that might be...

Comment: I just noticed the query works fine when using a different database and collection... could it be that my database bson is corrupted?

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense. Not sure how you'd check though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have tried that earlier.

The problem is not the query, but the BSON datafile of the collection was corrupted somehow. I had to drop the collection, then re-try.

Luckily, the collection was empty as I am early in development.

Answer (score 0):

eoo means end-of-object and if it's not there, you may well have a parse error in your JSON. Possibly Mongo wants strictly valid JSON, so you may need to use double quotes for all strings and maybe remove the new Date() bit.

http://jsonlint.com/ suggested that this would be valid, whereas the code you posted isn't. Not sure if that'll help or not as Mongo uses BSON, so may be more flexible.

```
{
    "created at": {},
    "ooc": false,
    "body": "<p>Moo</p>\n",
    "keywords": [
        "Moo"
    ],
    "mentioned": [],
    "tags": [],
    "sender": {
        "_id": "stuff",
        "name": "lambdadusk",
        "displayname": "Lambda"
    }
}
```